# If a class "A" has a pointer to a another class "B" can A access class B public methods

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

Just moved from programming in c to c++, Still learning everyday.
I am stuck with some compile issue .
Say I have a class `Element`, class `Log` and another derived class of `Element` call it as `Rx`. Now from class `Log` I want to access `class Element` public method. Please suggest some way to do that if you think the way I am doing is not right way to do it.
The first method I tried is to add a pointer to `Element` class in class `Log` and then tried to access the method.
The second method I tried to pass the reference/pointer to the class `Log:initialize(Element *element)`.
adding a code snippet below.

**Method1:**

```
class Element {
public:
    void add_handler(int param);
    // ..... other member and methods
}
class Rx: public Element {
     //...... other methods
     Log record;
}
class Log {
public:
      void initialize() {
         e->add_handler(10);
      }
private:
    Element *e;
}
```

**Method2:**

```
class Element {
public:
    void add_handler(int param);
    // ..... other member and methods
}
class Rx: public Element {
public:
     // ...... other methods
     Log record;
}
class Log {
      void initialize(Element *element) {
         element->add_handler(10);
      }
private:
    Element *e;
}
```

in both code I am getting same error "**error: invalid use of non-static member function**" which is in the function initialize where I am trying to accessing `e->add_handler`.

Would love to understand why is the error coming and if you have any suggestion to do this.

Now for non-static function the class does not have any memory, so the statement `e->add_handler` does it points to any memory ? I assume not , then how does compile resolves it ?

Thanks everyone for any help.

Comment: "error: invalid use of non-static member function" there is nothing in your snippets that could cause that error. Please edit your question and include a [mcve].

Comment: The posted code looks okay, although there's this:  `class log record;`  -- perhaps you meant to put `class Log record;` instead?  (Btw the `class` keyword can be omitted, so e.g. `Log record;` would be the more common syntax)

Comment: "in both code I am getting same error "error: invalid use of non-static member function"" still isn't true for the code shown. One would get something about an inaccessible member.

Answer (score 1):

`add_handler()` is not defined under `public:` :-)

Member functions(also called methods) are `private:` by default (that is if nothing's specified) when using the `class` keyword & `public:` when `struct` is specified.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but that is public. I missed putting that.